# Async.waterfall : Callback is not a function / module.exports

Tags: node.js, callback, async.js

After few hours spent to try multiple solutions finding here, I decided to post my issue here about that **error** (throw on the first function in the async.waterfall : function1 ):

```
C:\wamp64\www\projet\app\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:80
    throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
    ^

TypeError: callback is not a function
at Query._callback (C:\wamp64\www\projet\app\model\mymodel.js:10:3)
at Query.Sequence.end (C:\wamp64\www\projet\app\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:88:24)
at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (C:\wamp64\www\projet\app\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:139:8)
at Query.EofPacket (C:\wamp64\www\projet\app\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:123:8)
at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\wamp64\www\projet\app\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:279:23)
at Parser.write (C:\wamp64\www\projet\app\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:76:12)
at Protocol.write (C:\wamp64\www\projet\app\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:39:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\wamp64\www\projet\app\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:103:28)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
```

I followed several posts but I'm not sure about the syntax or the way I builded my code in this controller and model. I think I miss something, but I don't know what :(

This is myController.js

```
const async = require('async');
const MyModel = require('../model/mymodel');

module.exports.respond = function(socket) {
socket.on('connectionUser', function(param1, param2, param3= 'false') {
    try {
        async.waterfall([
            async.constant(param1, param2, param3),
            MyModel.function1,
            MyModel.function2,
        ], function3);
    } catch (err) {
        // ERRORS handler
    }

function funtion3 (err, userInfos, res[0]) {}
```

And in mymodel.js

```
const db = require('../config);

module.exports.function1 = function(callback){
    let reqSql = 'SELECT ...';
    db.query(reqSql, function(err, res){
        if (err) return callback(err);
        return callback(null, res[0]);
    });
};

module.exports.function2 = function(userInfos, callback){
    let reqSql = 'SELECT ....'
    db.query(reqSql, function(err, res){
        if (err) return callback(err);
        return callback(null, userInfos, res[0]);
    });
};
```

Comment: Where are function3 and function 4 ?

Comment: Either edit the question and provide details correctly or refer the https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall async docs

Comment: thanks for your comment. I've edited my question and check the link you've added.

Answer (score 0):

as exactly the error message says.callback is not a function inside your nested functions within function1,function2,

You need to return callback from the nested functions

try this

```
const db = require('../config);

module.exports.function1 = function(callback){
    let reqSql = 'SELECT ...';
    db.query(reqSql, function(err, res){
        if (err) return callback(err);
        return callback(null, res[0]);
    });
};

module.exports.function2 = function(userInfos, callback){
    let reqSql = 'SELECT ....'
    db.query(reqSql, function(err, res){
        if (err) return callback(err);
        return callback(null, userInfos, res[0]);
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. I try your solution but the error stay the same